# P/Invoke gives AccessViolationException in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis

My goal is to call a native DLL via P/Invoke from an ASP.NET application. So far, I can successfully call the DLL from a Console app, or even from an OWIN server running on HttpListener, hosted in an Azure WorkerRole.

Troubles arise when I try to host the exact same code in ASP.NET/IIS, either in a simple ASP.NET app or in an Azure WebRole. In such a context, the call to the DLL throws an AccessViolationException.

From my research, it looks like the issue could come from the fact that the native DLL is not thread-safe - and a test trying to call it from concurrent threads even in a Console app throws the AVE, which shows that it's not thread-safe indeed. So I'm checking with the DLL's author on that.

But in the meantime, I'm still wondering if that's really the root cause of the crash on ASP.NET/IIS, because during my tests I only do one request at a time. So waiting for the thread-safety to be fixed, I wanted to know if you guys would be aware of other specificites that could cause the P/Invoke to fail in ASP.NET/IIS.

**UPDATE**

Based on my numerous tests, it turned out that the crash was caused by the DLL trying to load external files. In a non-IIS application, placing these files at the same folder level as the DLL just works; but on my dev machine for example, the same code running on IIS tries to look for the files in "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express".

So my question now is: is there a way to control the path where a simple `File.Open` would look for and if not, is there a way to get the default path so that I can copy the required files there at startup?

Thanks

Comment: Could be anything. Without any details, we can only speculate and guess.

Comment: As a follow-up, the DLL is now thread-safe but still crashes in ASP.NET. The author has also added an empty method that I can call successfully, so it's not related to the loading of the library but really the execution of the other methods. The track I'm exploring now is that the DLL has to load additional files that have to be located on the same folder level; wouldn't be surprised that this doesn't work in ASP.NET or more precisely in IIS.

Comment: Got it! I found out that it comes from the external files loaded by the DLL, as the system tries to locate them in "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express" on my dev machine. If I put the files there, it works like a charm. I'm editing the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What you observe simply indicates that you use relative paths. That means when running under IIS Express (not IIS) the process tries to search under `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express` as it assumes that's the base directory to use when interpreting the relative paths.

You should always use absolute paths instead of relative paths, and then this issue won't happen.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I don't have any control on that as the native DLL is not (and should not be) aware of the execution context; it just tries to fopen the files it requires in the "current folder". So what I need to achieve is to control what the "current folder" is, whatever the execution context is, and especially in ASP.NET.

Comment: @ThomasWeiss In that case your only hope is to patch the dll. It is impossible to change working directory of IIS or IIS Express as that might lead to other issues you won't expect.

Comment: And what if at startup, I call Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() and copy the files required by the DLL over there?

Comment: @ThomasWeiss, the working directory is a system path, and you might think twice before copying any files there. But at least that's a workaround you might try for this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't muck around with copying files on every app startup, that can only go south.

A better solution would be to get the provider of the DLL to add some code that checks the Windows Registry for a path value. If that value exists in the Registry, the DLL will attempt to load its associated libraries from the path in that value; otherwise it will fall back to attempting to load them from the DLL's current directory.